Failed to load the display the audio player in the chatscreen of the chat app
I am writing a chat app which can play audio file in the chatscreen of the app. After updating to Expo SDK 51, the app cannot load the chatscreen with audio message (but it used to work fine when I was using Expo SDK 48). The following are the error showed in the log when I opened the chatscreen with audio message:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Track' of undefined
This error is located at:
in AudioPlayerViewTest (created by Bubble)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Bubble)
in TouchableWithoutFeedback (created by Bubble)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Bubble)
in Bubble (created by ItemWithSeparator)
in ItemWithSeparator (created by CellRenderer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by CellRenderer)
in VirtualizedListCellContextProvider (created by CellRenderer)
in CellRenderer (created by VirtualizedList)
in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by VirtualizedList)
in VirtualizedListContextProvider (created by VirtualizedList)
in VirtualizedList (created by VirtualizedSectionList)
in VirtualizedSectionList (created by SectionList)
in SectionList (created by ChatScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ChatScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by PageContainer)
in PageContainer (created by ChatScreen)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ImageBackground)
in ImageBackground (created by ChatScreen)
in RNCSafeAreaView
in Unknown (created by ChatScreen)
in ChatScreen (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by StackNavigator)
in StackNavigator (created by MainNavigator)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by MainNavigator)
in MainNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by AppNavigator)
in AppNavigator (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by MenuProvider)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by MenuProvider)
in MenuProvider (created by App)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
in GestureHandlerRootView (created by App)
in Provider (created by App)
in App (created by withDevTools(App))
in withDevTools(App)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes

My code for the audio player is as follows:
`import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  HStack,
  Icon,
  Slider,
  Text,
  Button,
  NativeBaseProvider,
} from "native-base";
import { MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

function msToTime(millisec) {
  var seconds = (millisec / 1000).toFixed(0);
  var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  var hours = "";
  if (minutes > 59) {
    hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    hours = hours >= 10 ? hours : "0" + hours;
    minutes = minutes - hours * 60;
    minutes = minutes >= 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
  }

  seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
  seconds = seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
  if (hours != "") {
    return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  }
  return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

export const AudioPlayerViewTest = (props) => {
  const {    audioUrl,  } = props;
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);  
  const sound = useRef(new Audio.Sound());
  const [currentDuration, setCurrentDuration] = useState(0);
  const [totalDuration, setTotalDuration] = useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadAudio();
  }, []);

  async function loadAudio() {
    setLoaded(false);
    setLoading(true);
    const checkLoading = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
    if (checkLoading.isLoaded === false) {
      try {
        const result = await sound.current.loadAsync({ uri: audioUrl });
        if (result.isLoaded === false) {
          setLoading(false);
          console.log("Error in Loading Audio");
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
          setLoaded(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } else {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  async function playAudio() {
    try {
      loadAudio();
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      console.log(result);

      if (result.isLoaded) {
        console.log("Play Audio");
        await sound.current.playAsync();
        // setPlayable(true);
        setIsPlaying(true);
        setActive(true);
      }

      sound.current.setOnPlaybackStatusUpdate((playbackStatus) => {
        if (playbackStatus.isPlaying) {
          setCurrentDuration(playbackStatus.positionMillis);
          setTotalDuration(playbackStatus.durationMillis);
        }
        if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
          setIsPlaying(false);
          setActive(false);
          setCurrentDuration(0);
          sound.current.unloadAsync();
          loadAudio();
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Cannot Play Audio");
    }
  }

  async function pauseAudio() {
    try {
      const result = await sound.current.getStatusAsync();
      if (result.isLoaded) {
        if (result.isPlaying === true) {
          console.log("Pause Audio");
          sound.current.pauseAsync();
          setIsPlaying(false);
          setActive(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Cannot Pause Audio");
    }
  }

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <HStack
        w="100%"
        p={1}
        justifyContent={"space-between"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        space={0}
        bg={active ? "blue.50" : "grey.50"}
        borderRadius={5}
      >
        <Button
          borderWidth={0}
          variant="outline"
          colorScheme="blue"
          onPress={!isPlaying ? playAudio : pauseAudio}
        >
          <Icon
            as={MaterialIcons}
            name={!isPlaying ? "play-arrow" : "pause"}
            color={!isPlaying ? "grey.300" : "blue.400"}
            style={{ transform: [{ rotateY: "0deg" }] }}
          />
        </Button>

        <Slider
          w="50%"
          size="sm"
          colorScheme={"blue"}
          defaultValue={0}
          value={currentDuration}
          minValue={0}
          maxValue={totalDuration == 0 ? 100 : totalDuration}
          accessibilityLabel="Audio Player"
          step={1}
          isReadOnly={true}
        >
          <Slider.Track bg={"grey"} size={2}>
            <Slider.FilledTrack bg={"blue.400"} size={2} />
          </Slider.Track>
          <Slider.Thumb bg={"blue.400"} ml={-2} />
        </Slider>
        <Text
          fontFamily={"body"}
          color={active ? "blue.600" : "grey.400"}
          mr={2}
        >
          {msToTime(currentDuration)} / {msToTime(totalDuration)}
        </Text>
      </HStack>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
};`


Also, anyone has ideas on how I can modify the function playAudio( ) as I feel strange that the loadAudio has to appear twice (The purpose of that is to make the playback to go back to time =0 after direct finished playing).
Thanks in advance!
